# UITableView scrolls bounces back to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've been to a lot different questions on StackOverflow, But I just can't figure what is wrong here.
I have a view controller that receives data from a JSON, creating an array, and, then, it builds an UITableView, with fixed heights. 
The issue is that I can't scroll to the bottom. It just bounces back.

```
- (UITableViewCell* )tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  [cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:2];

  NSDictionary* place = [_placesData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [cell.textLabel setText:[place valueForKey:@"nome"]];
  [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[place valueForKey:@"endereco"]];
  [cell.detailTextLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
  [cell.detailTextLabel sizeToFit];
  UIImage* originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"encontre.png"];
  UIImage* resized = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]scale:(originalImage.scale * 1.8) orientation:(originalImage.imageOrientation)];
  cell.imageView.image=resized;
  cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:17];
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:17];

  self.tableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
  self.tableView.bounces=YES;
  [self.tableView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
  return cell;
}
```

I have no idea on what else to do. Already tried to set the `contentSize.height` manually, force `bounces` and `scrollEnabled` on almost evert piece of code on the view controller.

Regards.

Comment: Those last three lines before the `return`—the ones to set the scrolling and bouncing behavior—do not belong in this method. Better to put them in your `UITableViewController` subclass’s `init` method, since those properties should only need to be set once.

Comment: Assuming you're using interface builder to work with the main layout? Are all of those autosizing properties set correctly? Nothing in this method looks too bad aside from @bdesham's comment (which still wouldn't cause the issue you're seeing).

Comment: Sure looks like that tableview frame is going below visible view. (being much bigger than You are seeing) Could You enable side scrollbars? when You scroll (pull up), You will see if side scrollbars move outside visible tableview frame - thus would mean that frame is much too big. Do You have any scrollViewDidScroll delegate methods?  Another option would be to fill tableview with - like - 100 records. Then see if it allows scrolling and doesn't bounce back.

Comment: @bdesham How can I do it? What is the signature for the `init` method?

@jterry Yes, I'm using Interface Builder. What Is the correct settings? I have Use AutoLayout on.

Comment: @GuntisTreulands I don't have any scrollViewDidScroll method. The only methods for table that I have implemented are `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSelection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just managed to solve it, if anyone is having this same issue.

What I did is, inside the size inspector for my UiTableView, I manually set "Row Height" at 70 (the exact size I'm using).

After this, everything worked as a charm. But, if anyone can give a comprehensive explanation on what is really happening in here, it would be really great.

Answer (score 2):

The way UITableView works is that it requires to know each row height in order to be able to compute its size.

The default behavior is to assume each row height is 44px. Which was clearly not your case here as you said it was 70px. That's why you had to change it in order to be able to scroll all way down

For instance let's say you had 10 rows. With default row height your table view was only able to scroll down to 10*44 = 440px thus the bouncing effect you got.
By setting the row height to 70px your tableview now goes down to 10*70 = 700px

Answer (score 1):

can you check in the xib of your ViewController, select your tableView and click "size inspecto" in the right menu and you change in "iOS 6/7 Deltas":
you can tape -20 in height

i think the problem is in adaptation with ios7 and 6

Comment: There isn't an option like this over here... Everything i get on my Size Inspector is Table View Size, Scroll View Size, View and Constraints (that is actually empty)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

My solution was to update the contentSize before reloading the table's data.

```
tableViewOffre.contentSize = CGSizeMake(tableViewOffre.frame.size.width, [app.offres count] * 105);
```

Where 105 is my row height.

I think it isn't the best way to solve the problem (pretty dirty way I guess) but it's the only solution found.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, don't let it get assigned automatically (i.e. `sizeToFit`). `UITableView` can be very unpredictable if you are not very specific and if you don't override certain methods.
I had a unique problem with tableView scrolling back up to top automatically after I called `[tableView reloadData]`; This problem was unique because it only happened on iPad mini and iOS 8, every other device and OS was working properly. Hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 1):

Actually your problem is related to frame of the table. by setting "Row height" is working for you because by chance count of row in your table and row height giving a table height that is suitable to you. But its not the right way of doing this. 
Somewhere you need to check height of the table may be something like

> Blockquote
>   (nameArray.count<10?kSACellHeight*nameArray.count:kSACellHeight*11))

Answer (score 0):

I've met with same issue.In my situation,I drag a tableview to a custom view controller,which is presented by a push segue.If the amount of data showed in tableview exceeds some number,then I can't touch the cell on bottom of the tableview.

Many ways have been tried:set the frame/content size of the table view,and none works for me.Finally,I find the root cause and solve it in a simple way(although not gracefully).

First,the root cause:the table view created by IB has a width larger then the its parent view controller.Thus,any cell out of view's bound will not be touched.

So,the solution is simple:Go to StoryBoard,adjust the width of table view,making it smaller than the width of parent view.It seems that if one table view is created by StoryBoard,you can't change its frame by code.That's what I've found up to now. I guess it's a bug of StoryBoard.

Help it be useful for other guys.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, my solution uses constraints. I ran across this issue while making a UITableView that can have a dynamic number of cells expand with more details. Here was my structure:

- UIView

  - UIStackView

    - UIView (My Tabs Segue View)
    - UIView (My First Tab View)

      - UITableView (My Table I Wanted to be Scrolled)
      - UIView (My View if that Table was Empty)
    - UIView (My Second Tab View)

      - UITableView (My Second Table I Wanted to be Scrolled)
      - UIView (My View if that Table was Empty)

So, what I found out was that when I was setting the height constraint of the tables to the `contentSize` of the tables themselves. This originally helped account for the expandable part of the cell. But, if you want a table to be scrollable, you need to have its height **shorter** than its content height. By making it shorter (and having all the xib checkboxes checked as mentioned in other posts), it will automatically scroll. Granted, you can set its height via constraint or any way you want, just make sure its not the same as its content height!